# Dart: Instance of 'Class' during obtaining String from List<Class>

Tags: arrays, list, dart, instanceof, custom-data-type

I am facing with the problem during obtainign String data from the List
I created a class call called "Task" with the property 'final String statement;' and constructor containing my statement. Also was created List with the listed tasks.

I can not obtain String from that List. Every try ends with: "Instance of 'Task'", insead of displaying my wanted String.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuDQb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class Task {
  final String statement;

  Task({this.statement});

  @override
  String toString() => statement;
}
```

Or this:

```
class Task {
  final String statement;

  Task({this.statement});

  @override
  String toString() => 'Task: $statement';
}
```

Comment: That was really helpfull. Thank You! But as You can see, I tried to add String to the List<Task> decisions. Displaying the String from the List as per Your instructions was good, but how about adding new item to the list? I can not figure out this completely.

Comment: You must provide a source code, not an image. It is not accepted here. So that others can execute your code. The less code the better.

Comment: Where and what result value you get? What result you want? I cannot understand your problem.

Comment: @mezoni does the `@override` for `toString` mean its returning the `statement` String if an instance of Task is printed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {

  
  print(ImportantDecisions().decisions[0]);
  ImportantDecisions goodDecision = ImportantDecisions();
  goodDecision.addDecision("Be perfect!");
  goodDecision.obtainTask();
  
  
}

class ImportantDecisions{

  List<Task> decisions = [
    Task(statement: "Be awasome!"),
    Task(statement: "Be good!"),
  ];
  
  void addDecision(String newImportantValue) {
    final userDecision = Task(statement: newImportantValue);
    decisions.add(userDecision);
    print(decisions.last);
  }
  
  String obtainTask() {
  return decisions.toString();
  }
  
}

class Task{
  
final String statement;
  Task({this.statement});
  
}
```